# How can I override the method 'ConfigureAuthentication' IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, identityserver4

The main ConfigureAuthentication is in `StartupDomainServiceBase.cs` in a separate container. I´m working with Webhooks so my token is in the body from the request (it is usually in header). So I tried my best and added  `options.TokenRetriever = CustomTokenRetriever.FromBody`  to the main Authentication function, but this affects the other containers that are reading the token from header.
So I have to set this configuration only in the `Startup.cs`  from the Container where my Project is.
How can I do that?

`Startup.cs`  inherits from  `StartupDomainService` , and so as I can see, they override some methods from there in order to costumize them. (for example ConfigurCustomServices or ConfigureAuthorization). But when I tried to override  `ConfigureAuthentication`  it says that it can´t be done because its sealed, but the other methods are also sealed... I don´t get it...

Has someone an idea or a suggestion? It would be very helpful.

(btw. im working with c#, Visual Studio, Docker Container, nginx serv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps add a custom middleware in the ASP.NET Core pipeline, that can inspect the incoming requests and if a token is found in the body, then it is added as a header in the HttpContext, so that the authentication system is happy?

Alternative you can add a proxy in front of your service (like [Yarp](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-yarp-preview-1/)) that does this transformation for you.

Comment: This is a good idea, I ended up creating my own Method to check if the token is in body or not :) and I packed it in options.TokenRetriever! thank u very much for invest your time on my question!